# How to politely ask someone "I need your help"

Tags: word-choice

I need to ask a school administrator a few questions. What is the polite way to start my email "I need your help"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polite way of calling someone for help](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40298/polite-way-of-calling-someone-for-help)

Answer (score 3):

I would start with a simple:

`Dear [Mr./Mrs. Name of administrator],`

Then the best way to phrase it would be to jump right into the question without *I need your help*, because saying so makes it sound as though you have more of an urgent, sensitive, personal problem than a simple question or two (they might be a bit taken aback by the phrase).

However, if you have several questions (let's say more than 2), or if you just want to sound a bit more polite, you could preface the content with a phrase like *I was wondering I you might be able to answer a few questions of mine*, or, *I have a few questions that I was hoping you might be able to help me with*.

Answer (score 1):

*"I'm hoping you can assist me with..."*

*"I'm hoping you can help me with..."*

*"I have [some issue] you may be able to help/assist me with..."*

Depending on the exact nature of the question, you may want to avoid being *too* polite and go with a more blunt/urgent approach:

*"I require your assistance with..."* (sounds a little more formal than "I need help")